# Не работают скрипты плагина на подгружаемом ajax контенте, как правильно подключить?

Tags: javascript, ajax

На подгружаемом аяксом контенте не работают плагины, а именно `Magnific Popup`.
Для временного решения я использую:

```
$( '#contentBody' ).on( 'click' , 'a' , function() { 
    $('.podrobnee , .popka-form').magnificPopup({type: 'inline'});
});
```

Но данное решение не подходит, потому что работает только со второго клика. 
Если кто знает как будет правильно подключить буду благодарен.